# Google Glass OnActivityResult not called for intent MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to take image followed by certain operations on that image. first part is working as expected :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_TAKE_PICTURE);
```

opens camera, take picture and say tap to accept. now as soon as i tap it, glass start showing  default scree "ok glass". Idealy it should call onActiviryResult.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult " + requestCode + " " + resultCode + " "data);

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

:( ........... no clue whats wrong with google glass :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't work for me either. It's a bug in their latest update, XE19.1. Issues have been filed and sent to Google, so it should be taken care of and fixed in the next update.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=555

Comment: No problem. It drove me nuts as well when I sat down searching through the code for any way to bypass it. There's probably some way, but not something that I could find before starting on another work-around.
My solution was, at least for the moment, to not use 'startActivityForResult' and 'onActivityResult' and implement the camera on my own with the Camera API (like #12 said in the link above). A bit more code to write, but not impossible. And you have more control over what's happening. :-)